Как сделать разноцветный текст в Editor?
Как сделать разноцветный текст в Editor .NET MAUI? Везде пишется только как сделать цвет всего текста в описании формы Editor в xaml файле - TextColor, но это настройка формы для всего текста целиком.
Делаю текстовую игру для Android, в ней есть поле вывода многострочного текста - Editor. В поле должен добавляться текст построчно, как в чате. Некоторые символы выделяются другим цветом, курсивом.
Делал тоже самое на WPF для пк, там есть контейнер TextBlock.Inlines, в который добавляется объект Run. Run состоит из текста и его форматирования. Каждому символу можно было дать цвет и стиль. Можно было сделать TextBlock.Inlines.Add(outputRun) и текст отображался.
Есть ли что-то подобное в MAUI? Ну или что-то другое, которое выводит разноцветный текст?

"Что-то другое" есть, но только при "нативной" разработке.

Выводить форматированный текст (цвет, стиль) позволяет поле Label.
Документация
Поле Editor такое не может. Поэтому воспользуюсь полем Label для своего проекта.
